# Can't set up Touch ID on iPhone 6+

Tags: iphone, touch-id

I have an iPhone 6+ that was given to me by the original owner because she thought she had bricked it while attempting to set it up for a family member.

Using DFU mode I have un-bricked it, but one problem remains, I can't set up Touch ID. During initial setup, & every time I've gone to set Touch ID up in the Settings app, I see the setup screen for less than a second before it goes to a screen saying, "**Failed** Unable to to complete Touch ID setup. Please go back and try again." I've tried with a SIM installed & that makes no difference.

[image: Touch ID set up failed]

Comment: Has the screen or the Home button been replaced?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica, to the best of my knowledge not, but I can & will check.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what happens when the Touch ID sensor has been replaced and not paired with the secure enclave.

If you don’t have the original sensor to put back in the phone, an Apple authorised service provider can replace the sensor and perform the pairing process with the new sensor.

Comment: I shall visit my nearest Apple authorised service provider shortly. For the uses I'm going to put this phone to, it may not ne worth the expense.